# AMP HTML error : Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document'

Tags: amp-html

I am using 'AMP Html' and this error comes when I validate 'AMP Html' in Chrome Console. I see it everytime on adding any image.

Is this jquery error by the google AMP Html framework ?[image]

"v0.js:351 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'amp-img'. A type with that name is already registered."

Comment: Please show the URL so that we can see the full source. Google Developer Tool messages are particularly difficult to analyze without access to the source.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to take a wild guess from that screenshot, I'd say you were still including the old `amp-img` as a separate component, like this:

```
<script async 
        custom-element="amp-img" 
        src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-img-0.1.js">
</script>
```

This `amp-img` component is [now built into the core](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-img.js) library, so your inclusion of the separate `amp-img` component script would actually cause the `amp-img` component to register twice and thus throw an error.

Just make sure your code looks like [this](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/).

Answer (score 0):

For me the error message has stopped showing up.

The resolution was to use this:

`<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js">`